# How do you generate a new Rakefile for a Rails app that has "lost" its Rakefile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rakefile

Somehow my Rails app doesn't have a Rakefile. I don't know if it lost it or what.

So when I run:

```
rake gems:refresh_specs
```

I get:

```
No Rakefile found
```

How do I generate a new Rakefile to refresh my gem specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `rails` again to re-generate your application. To avoid overwriting existing files use the `-s` or `--skip` option. So from the directory above your rails app:

```
rails my_app -s
```

It will list the changes it makes which should just be your missing rake file unless you've been a bit keen to delete other things.

Comment: Nice, thanks! You can also pass in the --pretend flag before you run it to see the changes that it will make :)