# how to fix error while running rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

I was trying to run the following command but the result was not what i expected

rake db:create

the result:
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /mnt/c/newapp/config/application
/mnt/c/newapp/rakefile:4:in `require_relative' /mnt/c/newapp/rakefile:4:in` <top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

i tried reinstalling postgres but that did not solve the problem, I also tried to install all ruby's packages but it did not work at all.

Comment: Seems your app is missing its rakefile: `/mnt/c/newapp/rakefile` How did you create the app? Do you want to be creating a new app with Rails 4? Rails is at version 7.

Comment: this is how I created the app
rails new newapp -d postgresql and RAILS 7.0.4

Comment: Somehow you're missing your `rakefile`. Do you have a `Rakefile`?

Comment: If you're on Windows, Windows filenames are *sometimes* case-insensitive and *sometimes* they are not. If you're using something like Cygwin or Windows Subsystem For Linux it's possible you have a `Rakefile` but rails is looking for `rakefile`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683796/how-do-you-generate-a-new-rakefile-for-a-rails-app-that-has-lost-its-rakefile) for how to refresh your app.

Comment: i do have Rakefile with capital R, could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, somehow a file was generated a file with the wrong case.

Comment: is there away to change the file name, without accessing manually, I mean just by using the terminal? am new to ubuntu and ruby so am asking a lot :p

Comment: It seems like you're running Ubuntu, but you're working on a Windows/NTFS partition? That might be the problem, Windows file systems can lose case and cause Rakefile to become rakefile. Do the app on a native Ubuntu directory like your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that on line 4 of your rakefile the `require_relative "config/application"` line is failing, `"cannot load such file -- /mnt/c/newapp/config/application"`, do you somehow not have a `config/application.rb` file in your project?